# NSubstitute test for void method

Tags: c#, testing, nsubstitute

I would like to verify that the parameter `idStatus` is assigned to the `myObj` instance. 
How can I do this with NSubstitute? I thought that if I somehow could verify the parameter to `UpdateObject` this would be a good test of the method, but not sure how to do this. Any thoughts?

```
public void SetObjectStatus(int id, int? idStatus)
{
    var myObj = GetObject(id);
    myObj.IdStatus = idStatus;

    UpdateObject(myObj);
}


[TestMethod]
public void SetObjectStatus_Verify()
{
    //Arrange
    int id = 1;
    int? newStatus = 10;

    //Act
    test.SetObjectStatus(id, newStatus);

    //Assert
    //?? I would like to check that myObj.IdStatus equals newStatus (10).
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether you want to test the internals (*white box testing*) or just the result (*black box testing*).

For the first: does your code give you the flexibility that `GetObject(id)` can be set up so that it actually returns a mock? If so, you can set up a mock with `var mock = Substitute.For<IYourObject>()` and call `mock.Received().IdStatus` ([see here](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/received-calls/)).

For the second: you need to call `GetObject(id)` within your test method and see whether the expected value is present.

Comment: It's all interfaces so flexibility is no problem. One question though. It seems that it's not possible to do a Received() for a method in the class currently under test. Is there a way around?

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide the complete code? Because when using `Received()`, you have to inject the mock somehow. How are you doing that? As far as I understand the docs, it should work that way...